# How to solve SpriteKit SKTexture's CGImage "Context leak"?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, core-graphics, metal, gamekit

Xcode 11-12, MacOS Catalina, Swift 5 project...

This code is produced "Context leak detected, msgtracer returned -1" error:

```swift
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import GameKit

func getTextureImage(_ index: Int, isSky: Bool = true) -> CGImage {
    
    let perlinSource = GKPerlinNoiseSource(
        frequency: 1,
        octaveCount: 7,
        persistence: 0.5,
        lacunarity: 2.0,
        seed: 123
    )
    
    let noise = GKNoise(perlinSource)
    
    noise.gradientColors = [
        -1.0: NSColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.15, blue: 0.85, alpha: 1.0),
        1.0 : NSColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1.0),
    ]
    
    noise.move(by: vector_double3(Double(index), 0, 0))
    
    let noiseMap = GKNoiseMap(noise,
                              size: SIMD2(repeating: 1),
                              origin: SIMD2(repeating: 0.0),
                              sampleCount: SIMD2(repeating: 16),
                              seamless: false)
    
    let t = SKTexture(noiseMap: noiseMap)
    let i = t.cgImage()
    
    return i
}


for x in 0...128 {
    
    let texture = getTextureImage(x)
    
}
```

How to solve that error at line with `.cgImage()` method call?
I need CGImage data from colored **GKNoiseMap**, then I will use it with MetalKit to load data into **MTLTexture** with

```swift
MTKTextureLoader.newTexture(cgImage: texture, options: textureLoaderOptions)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeahh, of course I tried

```swift
autoreleasepool {
    let t = getTextureImage(x)
}
```

and solved problem :) So, you have to use `autoreleasepool` with NSImage and CGImage in Swift API